# How to update RecyclerView without recreating (restarting) the activity. I use SQLite Database to store and retrieve data to the Recycler view

Tags: java, android

As far as I know there are two ways

1- using `startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);`

2- Override `onResume();` method and put update method inside `onResume();`

which neither of these two ways are efficient.

The first method recreates the activity every time I add a note to SQLite Database, the second method every time I press home button the RecyclerView gets updated though there is no need to update because the data hasn't changed in that situation.

What is the third way to update the RecyclerView whenever SQLite data has changed?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362055/problem-in-positioning-two-row-layouts-one-below-each-other-with-multiview-recyc/72419542#72419542) answer might help you. Questions are different but the answer includes a possible answer for your problem too.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I don't want to Override onResume() method and put update code inside onResume because every time onResume called the data gets updated. If The data is not changed, it is not necessary to update. Update must called whenever the data change happened. Let's say I press the home button and open the app again, here why RecyclerView gets updated when RecyclerView hasn't been changed?

Comment: Hmm I see, How do you manage your sqlite database operations? Do you use a database helper for example? Also give some details about your application structure ie. where do you list the data, where do you get the data from user etc.

Comment: @Kozmotronik this is my example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362055/problem-in-positioning-two-row-layouts-one-below-each-other-with-multiview-recyc#72419542

Comment: @Kozmotronik  I want to improve app,  if the data hasn't changed I don't want to update RecyclerView even onResume(); get called. I want a listener to listen to the changes of sqlite data, if data hasn't change then don't call notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: If you really care about the performance you shouldn't use notifydatachanged at all. I woud suggest you to use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) along with [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) to make changes in more granularity and thus improve the performance unless you use sqlite obligatory.

Comment: @Kozmotronik So what you mean is, if I use SQLite there is no other otption either call onResume(); and updae data during onResume or restart the activity.

Comment: Not exactly. There are other options and other ways. For example it can be resolved using the livedata like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290726/get-data-from-sqlite-database-as-livedata-android. But it all the same, livedata will notify you when a change occurs but livedata will not know what changed, it will present the whole list. Then you set the list of adapter and call notifydatachanged that will result in recreating or rebinding all visible items which is a poor performance relatively. But knowing wich data has changed and updating that particular data, not all, is better.

Comment: @Kozmotronik last questions: 1- if I use Room with DiffUtill, is that solve recreating the activiy or avoid update Recyclerview inside onResum() for my case? 2- If I continue with SQLite there is no way to avoid recrating the activity or avoid updating RecyclerView inside onResume?

Comment: Last answers :)) 1- Yes, by using room - livedata - diffutil you don't have to recreate the activity. Just a few one time initializations in `onCreate` and done. 2- Despite using sqlite you don't have to recreate the activity by calling the `startActivity` everytime an object has been added in the database. You can use livedata or even an interface between the activity and the database helper will do the job without recreating the activity.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

> Use Swipe to refresh layout

**activity_main_xml**

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
           //TODO operation
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but this even makes it worse, it is not possible nor reasonable to swipe RecyclerView every time the user added a note to the RecyclerView. I've seen a ton of note taking apps no-one ever implemented this.

Comment: Try this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have  called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); What I want is updating RecyclerView whenever I return from ActivityB to MainActivity without recreating or restarting the MainActivity.